# Should I close very old feature requests

Tags: planning, project-management-style, features

Our product backlog contains 1000s of feature requests. Some of these are 5 or more years old and have not had any updates since they were first raised.

My colleague argues that these are still valid and should remain open.

I think that we are unlikely to address these and it’s more honest to close them. It also makes it easier to see what we WILL work on.  They remain in the system and can always be reopened if they come up again.

What is the best approach?

Comment: Is this not a call that the Product Owner should make?

Comment: Ask for budgeting these and increased resources support, present your plan to sponsor and request owners.

Answer (score 6):

> Should I close very old feature requests?

Yes.

A backlog with 1000 items is rarely a backlog. For a big product, with many team's working on it, maybe that's fine. But something that contains five year old items is most likely not a proper backlog. It's simply a dump of ideas that someone once had and placed them there for "safe keeping" or because it's "a shame to get rid of them".

Get rid of them.

They polute your backlog and are a distraction. If they were important or valuable, they would have already been implemented into the product a long time ago. If they will be important some time in the future, you will just recreate them then.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that age alone should be a factor in deciding if you should delete or close a feature request. Feature requests should only be removed if they are beyond the current scope of the product vision and are not appropriate for being implemented. By not closing the request, you can keep track of the people who requested it, when it was requested, and if and when the request recurs.

In my view, closing is a final state. It is a definitive "we will not do this". Of course, that doesn't prevent people from asking in the future, which may get a different response. However, the difference between "this is very low priority and not actively being looked at" is a very different answer than "this will not be done".

If your concern is visibility, most electronic tools allow you to apply tags or labels. You can apply a label to these very low items to filter them from the team's view while still allowing them to be seen if desired as well as searchable.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly there are lot of ifs and buts here. In my opinion a feature not getting prioritized for more than 5 years is itself a sign that its obsolete. Practically speaking in this modern technology driven world results are expected much faster and a bunch of features just sitting there is of no use at all. You should just get rid of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the people/departments that reported those feature requests and ask them if they are valid or not. To do this, you can hold a series of workshops that everybody contributes to the validity of those requests.